# Can't access my folder because of WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed my WordPress on my website and I'm using permalinks, but I have a folder called x in the main root of my website I can't access it now when I type `http://mywebsite/x` it redirects me to error 404 not found. That's because WordPress is trying to fitch the story that called x in the database. How can I exclude that folder and its childern "folders" from wrodpress calculations?

Comment: tip: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com is the place for WordPress Questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file in the root of your website's directory contains a RewriteRule which redirects every incoming request to Wordpress's bootstrapper. It probably looks something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

You should add two Conditions to this Rule. These conditions provide exceptions that make sure the Rule is only executed if there is no (`!`) file (`-f`) or no directory (`-d`) available that matches the requested URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Tried this solution, but it is not working. Could you please take a look at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48809023/unable-to-upgrade-zencart-because-wordpress-is-not-allowing-to-access-subfolder

Answer (score 0):

check .htaccess file, that could be a problem. (redirection if page does not exist, in your case, http://mywebsite/x/index.html or .php does not exist)