# Unable to upgrade zencart because wordpress is not allowing to access subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, zen-cart

Okay,

I have a wordpress system https://example.com, everything works fine. Basically I also have zen cart installed in the system. https://example.com/shopcart/ is the url for zen cart.

I am trying to upgrade zencart to the latest version. For which, I have backed up the files and database.
I have uploaded the latest version zencart files to https://example.com/test/ and when I try to load https://example.com/test/zc_install/ I am redirected to a 404 page.

The `<title></title>` of the 404 page says 'Nothing found for  Test Zc_Install'. I am sure wordpress is looking for an article by this name. I have tried many solutions, but it is not working.

Below is my .htaccess:

```
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`
```

The system uses permalinks. The permalink is set to custom structure: http://example.com/%post_id%/%postname%/

I know that wordpress loads the root index.php file first and prepares the query. Is it possible to temporarily stop wordpress behaviours and allow me to access the URL https://example.com/test/zc_install/ ?

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress apache rewrite is catching all of your requests when they come into the website root directory.

You could add the following to the top of your Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# add this line to ignore all re-writes within the TEST folder.
RewriteRule ^test - [L,NC]
```

This will ignore all requests which contain the test/ directory.  I would then suggest that you add a separate .htaccess file within your Zen base folder to handle any smart SEO mods etc from there, rather than cluttering your main .htaccess file if possible.

Comment: Thank you, I added `RewriteRule ^test - [L,NC]` between `RewriteBase /` and `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`. Unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Update your rule to: `RewriteRule ^(test)($|/) - [L,NC]` and see if that solves your issues.  Can you access a simple .html page within the test/ folder?

Comment: No Sir, no luck. didn't work. Regarding the html file, I cannot access it with and without the rule you specified.

Comment: I am able to access https://example.com/test/zc_install/sql where sql is another folder inside zc_install. The folder sql contains 4 subfolders only. No files. Actually I can see the empty directory listing of sql.

Comment: It's odd that you can access the /test/zc_install/sql folder, but not the test/ folder itself, as both would be handled in the first instance by the same root .htaccess file.  My next suggestion would be to ensure there are no other .htaccess files or rules impeding your access.  To do this, create a folder called test2 or similar, add a similar rule to that above to allow access to this folder, and see if it is blocked.  If you can access it, it would point to multiple .htaccess files on your server, with the issue being further along the hierarchy.

Comment: Out of interest, when you say you are unable to access the zc_install folder, what error do you get?

Comment: Reply to the above comment(what error do you get?) -> I just simply get redirected to the 404 page.

Comment: Sir, added test2 folder. With my default htaccess, I get the directory listing of test2 folder and for test folder, I get redirected to 404.. The folders 'test' and 'zc_install' do have an index.php in them while test2 do not have one. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Add a simple index.php file to the test2/ folder and just put the line <?php die("page found"); ?> in it.  It sounds like there may be a .htaccess file within your test/ folder which is blocking your access to both the store and the install folder.

Comment: This is my current htaccess `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(test)($|/) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(test2)($|/) - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`        With this, I have added the index.php inside test2 folder like you said and I am able to access it. the page shows 'page found'

Comment: I have an htaccess within my test/zc_install folder.

Comment: \Perfect, so now you know that the htaccess file within the ROOT directory is operating correctly, and ignoring requests to both TEST & TEST2 folders and index files within them.  Now it sounds to me like there is an htaccess within the TEST folder which is then causing you the issues.  Zen Cart ships with one by default, so it may be that you need to temporarily remove this, and see if this solves your problem.  You can simply rename it for speed and testing.

Comment: Sir, I am able to view the 'test2' but not the 'test' folder. There is no htaccess file in the 'test' folder. There is an htaccess within test/zc_install folder.

Comment: Ok, so just for sake of checking everything, change the name of the test folder to test2, and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Tried it. when I went to https://www.example.com/test2/zc_install/ it still redirecting me to 404 page. Not sure whats going on..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165351/discussion-between-biju-p-dais-and-absolute).

Comment: Figured it out finally. It was due my php version. My php version is 5.2. There was a line in the zencart folder/includes/classes/class.base.php (line#140): `return preg_replace_callback('/[_-]([0-9,a-z])/', function($matches) {return strtoupper($matches[1]);}, $rawName);`. This causes syntax error because it is supported only in php 5.3+. I commented it and the zc_install page popped up!!!. Going to upgrade zen cart. Thank you all for your help and support.! :)